# Microstrategy count blank fields

Tags: microstrategy

any idea on how to count blank fields in MicroStrategy.
I have two columns ID and Criticality, I need to check how many IDs have its criticality field empty.

I am trying to see if there is any function like ISNULL but I am not getting the results.

Answer (score 1):

If the ID is guaranteed to be present and you don't join to any other table it should be straight forward:

Suppose you have attribute **Vendor** with Attribute-Forms: **ID**, **CRITICALITY**.
This is how you get the number of entries where **Criticality** is NULL:

```
Sum<UseLookupForAttributes=False>(IF(IsNull(Vendor@TEST), 1, 0)) {~+, Vendor+}
```

There are other ways to achieve this, but you'd need to provide more context if you need something else.
More often than not simple solutions work for stripped down requirements but fail in multi-dataset-dossiers, because the real question behind is something more complex/else entirely. Therefore it's best to provide more detail in the question.

EDIT: the solution also works if attribute **Vendor** is swapped with attribute **Criticality**(CRITICALITY@ID) in the metric definition. If that's how your schema is built.
You should also be able to do this inline (f.e. in Dossiers).